# Branch coverage without branching - I know sounds weird

Tags: java, c#, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

I have a bunch of validation code that follows this pattern:

```cs
bool IsBroken()
{
    var isBroken = Check(..., "error-1")
        | Check(..., "error-2")
        ...
        | Check(..., "error-n");

    if (...)
    {
        isBroken |= Check(..., "error-1")
            | Check(..., "error-2")
            ...
            | Check(..., "error-n");
    }
    else
    {
        isBroken |= Check(..., "error-1")
            | Check(..., "error-2")
            ...
            | Check(..., "error-n");
    }

    // ...
    // Could have more if-else or even nested if-else

    return isBroken;
}

bool Check(bool condition, string message)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        errors.Add(message);
    }
    return condition;
}
```

The goal is to perform all checks regardless of the outcome. The problem with this code however, is that it's not branch coverage friendly.

A simple fix would be to replce `Check(bool, string)` with the function body obviously but this creates another lesser problem which is code clutter. I am trying to figure out a solution that can give me the best of both worlds. Any ideas?!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching

Comment: `isBroken` isn't really needed: `return !errors.isEmpty()`

Comment: Also, could use something like a `List<Validator>`, and iterate over the list where each list item encapsulates an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are so many repeating validations (if-checks) and they are quite short, you can create a dictionary of checks that needs to be done. Pass this dictionary to the method, iterate over items in the dictionary and add error message if validation error occurs.

Sample code:

```
class A
{
    Dictionary<Func<A, bool>, string> dictOfChecks = new Dictionary<Func<A, bool>, string>()
    {
        //Example of checks                 , Error Message
        { (arg) => arg.ToString().Length < 3, "Length is smaller than 3" },
        { (arg) => arg.ToString().Length < 2, "Length is smaller than 2" },
    };

    public bool IsBroken()
    {
        //there you can enter multiple call of GetErrors to check whether there are some
        var errors = GetErrors(dictOfChecks);

        return errors.Length == 0;
    }

    public string[] GetErrors(Dictionary<Func<A, bool>, string> dict)
    {
        var errors = new List<string>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Func<A, bool>, string> kvp in dict)
        {
            if (kvp.Key.Invoke(this))
                errors.Add(kvp.Value);
        }

        return errors.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with an ok solution:

```cs
_ = condition && Append("error");

bool Append(string error)
{
    errors.Add(error);
    return true;
}
```

while this can also be written as `if (condition) Append("error")`. In our case, block statements must be written as:

```
if (condition)
{
    ...
}
```